# How to select a all checkBox buttons in tableview cell by clicking select all button in ios

Tags: ios, uitableview, checkbox, uibutton, togglebutton

Hi I am using checkbox Functionality  for tableview cell for that i am taking a button in tableview cell and another button in navigation bar when i am clicking on navigation bar button i want to select all buttons with other image like checkBox and perform individual checkbox for every table view cell button any help thanks in advance

Comment: What did you try and what went wrong? What's your data model?

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest two ways, check whichever is feasible to you :)

Dont use images for cell as that will unnecessarily increase the weight of cell. You can make use of accessoryView.

Method 1: Store all the indexpath of the cell which is selected by user.
Create a an NSMutableArray to hold the index paths lets call it as SelectedIndexPathArray.

```
     - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
           if([SelectedIndexPathArray containsObject: indexPath]){
                 cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
           }
           else{
                cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
           }
       return cell;
}
```

Now when user taps on select all button add all the indexpaths of the tableview to array :)
You can do that easily you will get code snippet as well :)

And when user taps on individual cell all you have to do is :)

```
    -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
        if([SelectedIndexPathArray containsObject: indexPath]){
                     cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
                     [SelectedIndexPathArray removeObject:indexpath];
               }
               else{
                    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
                    [SelectedIndexPathArray addObject:indexpath];
               }
}
```

Thats all buddy :) 
Method 2: Its a different approach lemme suggest if this approach does not work to you :) lemme know :)

Happy coding

Comment: Thanks for the replay but i need second  approach because i need to handle with the images only so if you don't mind can you please help me out

Comment: what is the issue if you want to use image buddy??? Use the same approach, instead of cell.accessoryType have an imageview on top of cell and rather then setting cell.accessoryType = whatever ; make your image hidden or visible thats all :)

Comment: second method I mentioned is to work without an array buddy :) whether you use image or accessory type wont make any difference :) Ultimately logic is same :) save the indexpath of all the cell which is selected by user and in cell for row at indexpath hide or show tickmark :) If you are concerned about finding indexpath of cell when you tap on image of the cell, simplest way is use the tag attribute of imageview and set the row value of indexpath and recreate indexpath from that :)

Comment: Thank you so much you save my time

Answer (score 0):

1)take one global **bool isAllSelected** in that .m file

2) on naviagtion bar button click make that bool to true and reload tableview

3) and in cellForRowAtIndexMethod make one condition

```
if (isAllSelected) {
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"checked.png"];
}
else
{
// set default image
}
```